# debian 8.6 + iptables NAT

Tags: linux, сеть, nat

Не получается настроить нат...

Дано: eth0 - провайдер, br0 - дом. сеть; Клиент включен в сервер и статично задан адрес 192.168.1.2 , при это с клиента доступен шлюз и недоступно ничего более. Со шлюза доступно всё - и клиент, и интернет. Ниже инфа с него же.

```
    ### NAT config ###

    iptables -F
    iptables -t nat -F
    iptables -t raw -F
    iptables -t mangle -F

    iptables -A FORWARD -i br0 -o eth0 -s 192.168.1.0/24 -j ACCEPT
    iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o br0 -d 192.168.1.0/24 -j ACCEPT 
    iptables -P FORWARD DROP

    iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.1.0/24 -o eth0 -j SNAT --to-source 10.0.0.12

    # ip a
    1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default 
        link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
        inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
           valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
        link/ether 00:12:11:8c:df:97 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
        inet 10.0.0.12/24 brd 10.0.0.255 scope global eth0
           valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    3: eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast master br0 state UP group default qlen 1000
        link/ether 00:12:11:8c:df:98 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    4: br0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default 
        link/ether 00:12:11:8c:df:99 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
        inet 192.168.1.1/24 scope global br0
           valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

    # brctl show 
    bridge name bridge id       STP enabled interfaces
    br0     8000.0025183cfd32   no      eth1
                                        veth0

    # ip r
    default via 10.0.0.1 dev eth0 
    10.0.0.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.0.0.12
    10.0.0.0/14 via 10.0.0.1 dev eth0 
    192.168.1.0/24 dev br0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.1.1 

    # iptables -nvL
    Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 34 packets, 3377 bytes)
     pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

    Chain FORWARD (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
     pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
        0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  br0   eth0     192.168.1.0/24       0.0.0.0/0           
        0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  eth0    br0    0.0.0.0/0            192.168.1.0/24      

    # iptables -t nat -nvL
    Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 5148 packets, 591K bytes)
     pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

    Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 437 packets, 75668 bytes)
     pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

    Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 27 packets, 3179 bytes)
     pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

    Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 27 packets, 3179 bytes)
     pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
        0     0 SNAT       all  --  *      eth0    192.168.1.0/24       0.0.0.0/0            to:10.0.0.12

    # tcpdump -ni br0 host 8.8.8.8
    tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
    listening on br0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
    19:31:24.519733 IP 192.168.1.2 > 8.8.8.8: ICMP echo request, id 512, seq 1282, length 40
    19:31:30.019820 IP 192.168.1.2 > 8.8.8.8: ICMP echo request, id 512, seq 1538, length 40
    ^C

    # tcpdump -ni eth0 host 8.8.8.8
    tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
    listening on eth0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes


    ^C
```

Что я забыл?

Comment: Форвардинг включен? `cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward` что показывает

Comment: LOL, вот я идиот, самое основное забыл - включить роутинг в ядре. Вот что значит заработался... В общем, `echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward` , Спасибо @Andrew Hobbit